# Carregar arquivo .SQL e executar com PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Bom estou montando um pequeno código em PHP 8, PDO e Mysql 8. Ele vai ser responsável por criar um bando de dados e carregar as tabelas a partir de um arquivo .SQL

Até o momento estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
// Tenho as constantes de conexão
DB_HOST = "localhost";
DB_USER = "root";
DB_PASSWD = "";

// Aqui eu crio o novo Banco de dados
// Conexão
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Cria o BD
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `bdVirgem`";
$conn->exec($sql);
```

Bom até esse ponto esta ok, o banco e criado normalmente.
Bom agora vou carregar o conteúdo do arquivo .SQl em uma variável e depois passar isso para o PDO:

```
// Carrega o arquivo .SQL
$file = file_get_contents("bdVirgem.sql");

// Opções de conexão
$options = [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8; SET time_zone='America/Sao_Paulo';",
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
    PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL
];

// Conexão
$conn = new PDO(
    'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.$dbName.'',
    DB_USER,
    DB_PASSWD,
    $options
);

// Executas comandos do arquivo .sql
$stmt = $conn->prepare($file);
$stmt->execute();
```

Bom até aqui o Banco de dados e criado e as tabelas são carregados, porém estou tendo apenas um BUG.
No final do arquivo .sql  tenho as instruções de criação dos `Trigger`, eles não estão sendo criados.
Segue um exemplo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER removeProductCategory BEFORE DELETE ON productCategory
        FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE product SET categoryCode = null WHERE categoryCode = OLD.code;
    END;
    
    
    -- ++++++++++++
    
    
    CREATE TRIGGER removeCategory BEFORE DELETE ON category
        FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE cashBookEntry SET categoryCode = null WHERE categoryCode = OLD.code;
    END;
    
    
    -- +++++++++++
    
    
    CREATE TRIGGER addProductStock AFTER INSERT ON stockHandling
        FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE product SET stock = (stock + NEW.quantity), level = (level + 1) WHERE code = NEW.productCode;
    END;
    
    CREATE TRIGGER subProductStock AFTER DELETE ON stockHandling
        FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE product SET stock = (stock - OLD.quantity), level = (level - 1) WHERE code = OLD.productCode;
    END;
```

Bom alguém sabe onde o problema ocorre?

Comment: Experimente remover o `DELIMITER $` e troque `END$` por `END;` e remova `DELIMITER ;`

Comment: Tentei dessa forma e tive um erro: `#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a '' na linha 7`, Lembrando que tenho vários `Triggers` no arquivo. vou atualizar a pergunta com um exemplo.